# How does a Gaussian Process define a probability distribution in the functions space?

Tags: machine-learning, gaussian-process

I am studying Gaussian Process Regression. I will post a text from the book Gaussian Process for Machine Learning, by C. E. Rasmussen & C. K. I. Williams:

*We first consider a simple 1-d regression problem, mapping from an input x to an output f (x). In Figure 1.1 (a) we show a number of sample functions drawn at random from the prior distribution over functions specified by a particular Gaussian process which favors smooth functions. This prior is taken to represent our prior beliefs over the kinds of functions we expect to observe, before seeing any data.*

The definition of a Gaussian process that I know of is given by:

Definition (Gaussian process) A random process $\left(X_{t}\right)_{t \in T}$ is called a Gaussian process if, for any finite subset $T_{0} \subset T,$ the random vector
$$
\left(X_{t}\right)_{t \in T_{0}}
$$
has normal distribution. Equivalently, $\left(X_{t}\right)_{t \in T}$ is Gaussian if every finite linear combination
$$
\sum_{t \in T_{0}} a_{t} X_{t}
$$
is a normal random variable.

I would like to better understand the connection of this definition with the possibility of defining a distribution in the functions space, because to draw functions according to a distribution, I would have to define sigma algebras in the function space and a measure of probability in this sigma algebra. Or perhaps there is another meaning when we say "sample functions drawn at random from the prior distribution over functions specified by a particular Gaussian process".

Does anyone help to build this bridge?